# Copy Object Properties to a Map by Value not by Reference

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm not sure where i'm going wrong, but it seems that I'm not able to copy properties from an object instance and assign them to a map without the values being changed after saving the instance.

This is a sample class:

```
class Product {
    String productName
    String proudctDescription
    int quantityOnHand
}
```

Once the form is submitted and it's sent to my controller, I can access the values and manipulate them from the `productInstance.properties` map that is available from the instance. I want to copy the properties to another map to preserve the values before committing them during an edit. So let's say we are editing a record and these are the values stored in the db: `productName = "My Product"`, `productDescription = "My Product Description"` and `quantityOnHand = 100`.

I want to copy them to:

```
def propertiesBefore = productInstance.properties
```

This did not work, because when I save the productInstance, the values in propertiesBefore change to whatever the instance had.

So I tried this:

```
productInstance.properties.each { k,v -> propertiesBefore[k] = v }
```

Same thing happened again. I am not sure how to copy by value, it seems no matter what I try it copies by reference instead.

**EDIT**

As per the request of Pawel P., this is the code that I tested:

```
class Product {
    String productName
    String productDescription
    int quantityOnHand
}

def productInstance = new Product(productName: "Some name", productDescription: "Desciption", quantityOnHand: 10)

def propertiesBefore = [:]
productInstance.properties.each { k,v -> propertiesBefore[k] = (v instanceof Cloneable) ? v.clone() : v }

productInstance.productName = "x"
productInstance.productDescription = "y"
productInstance.quantityOnHand = 9

println propertiesBefore.quantityOnHand // this will print the same as the one after the save() 
productInstance.save(flush:true)    
println propertiesBefore.quantityOnHand // this will print the same as the one above the save()
```

Answer (score 4):

Without cloning, copying hash-map [:]'s values to a new hash-map [:]'s space can also be done by "pushing" the first one over, which would achieve the same result that you desired (copy by value)!

```
def APE = [:]
APE= [tail: 1, body: "hairy", hungry: "VERY!!!"]

def CAVEMAN = [:]
CAVEMAN << APE  //push APE to CAVEMAN's space

//modify APE's values for CAVEMAN
CAVEMAN.tail = 0
CAVEMAN.body = "need clothes"

println "'APE': ${APE}"
println "'CAVEMAN': ${CAVEMAN}"
```

Output ==>

```
'APE': [tail:1, body:hairy, hungry:VERY!!!]
'CAVEMAN': [tail:0, body:need clothes, hungry:VERY!!!]
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you actually copy references to variables. To obtain copy of variable you should use [`clone()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_%28Java_method%29). Take a look:

```
class Product {
    String productName
    String productDescription
    int quantityOnHand
}

def productInstance = new Product(productName: "Some name", productDescription: "Desciption", quantityOnHand: 10)

def propertiesBefore = [:]
productInstance.properties.each { k,v -> propertiesBefore[k] = (v instanceof Cloneable) ? v.clone() : v }

productInstance.productName = "x"
productInstance.productDescription = "y"
productInstance.quantityOnHand = 9

println productInstance.properties
println propertiesBefore
```

It prints:

```
[quantityOnHand:9, class:class Product, productName:x, productDescription:y]
[quantityOnHand:10, class:class Product, productName:Some name, productDescription:Desciption]
```

Comment: I just tried this code, with one modification, I saved the productInstance.save(flush:true) and printed out quantityOnHand before and after the save, the value was still referenced and not copied.

Comment: I pasted the code in the question as to what i ran. I'm just surprised that copying a map from one place to another is such a big deal. At bare minimum, when I loop the properties, I should be able to copy the values to a new map without copying the reference.

Comment: Okay, thank. But I'm not sure if I get what's the behaviour you want to achieve. The pasted code will print `10` before and after invoking `save()` - isn't it okay? If not what you expect before and after `save()`?

Comment: But `10` is the value before product save and modifications, right? (The value in `productInstance` after modification and save is `9`).

Comment: For some reason the value for both when I print them out is the same, I cannot for the life of me figure out what is happening.

Comment: Value of `propertiesBefore.quantityOnHand` is `10` and value of `productInstance.quantityOnHand` is `9`. You've printed the same value (`propertiesBefore.quantityOnHand`) before and after `save()`.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler example for groovy using Hash-Map [:] can be like this:

```
def APE = [:]
APE= [tail: 1, body: "hairy", hungry: "VERY!!!"]    

def CloneMe = APE  //*APE as clone*

def CAVEMAN = [:]    //*copy APE's values over thru mapping the clone*
CloneMe.each { key,value -> CAVEMAN[key] = (value instanceof Cloneable) ? value.clone() : value } 

println "'CloneMe': ${CloneMe}"

//change some of the clone's values for CAVEMAN
CAVEMAN.tail = 0
CAVEMAN.body = "need clothes"

println "'APE': ${APE}"
println "'CAVEMAN': ${CAVEMAN}"
```

Output ==>

```
'CloneMe': [tail:1, body:hairy, hungry:VERY!!!]
'APE': [tail:1, body:hairy, hungry:VERY!!!]
'CAVEMAN': [tail:0, body:need clothes, hungry:VERY!!!]
```