# Updates to my List are not happening when updated in a closure or even a method when using operator overloading

Tags: java, groovy

1. Looks like when you pass your List into a method/closure Groovy creates a copy of your List within the closure or method and updates that so your changes  are not reflected once you exit!!! This is not the case if you use .add method
2. Why would Groovy want to change this most intuitive of behaviour for
   a Java developer when you use addition with Lists with the operator
   overloaded + sign ?
3. What would be the benefit from Groovy's point of view ?
4. If I were to uncomment the enhanced for loops in my code sample and comment out the addition of Lists using the + sign - it behaves as expected

*

```
List<String> b = ['man', 'lady']

def x = { List<String> p ->

    println delegate.getClass().getName()
    List<String> inx = ['dog','cat']
    /*for (String l : inx)
    {
        p.add(l)
    }*/
    p = p + inx //value of p is not reflected whence you exit

}

def xmethod(List<String> p)
{
    List<String> inx = ['monkey','lion']
    /*for (String l : inx)
    {
      p.add(l)
    }*/
    p = p + inx // value of p is not reflected whence you exit

}

x( b )
println b

xmethod( b )
println b
```

Answer (score 0):

Given: `p = p + inx` where `p`, `inx` are Lists

This can be read as: `p = p.plus(inx)`, which in Groovy is an overloaded
method that returns a new copy of the List passed in which of course
will have a new address in memory. And therefore it does not update the
List passed in.

When the method returns and comes of the stack the List created within
is removed, and is no longer there.

Where you use `p.plus(inx)` or  `p + inx` it is very important
especially if p is passed into your method and you would like your
changes to be reflected back to the original `p` that was passed in to
use the `p.addAll(inx)` method instead.

BTW the same is true of Maps as well and I refer you to: [Groovy (or Java) - Pass by reference into a wrapper object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329428/groovy-or-java-pass-by-reference-into-a-wrapper-object)